# looking for some exercise to test understanding of covector

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

I am trying to understand the concept of "covector" so that I can work with it for problems I come across in PDE.

My knowledge on differential geometry is very little. And my topological background is rather weak. I have tried to understand this concept by reading different notes but still not able to describe it in simple words. 
Could anyone suggest me some simple exercises on "covector" in getting the concept? I really could find any in books/notes.

Thanks

Comment: have you read http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240491/what-is-a-covector-and-what-is-it-used-for

Comment: of course, I have read this. But I am looking for an specific exercise.